# why i dont have right to execute systemtap?

Tags: systemtap

I wanna to run systemtap in my linux mint. I created three groups "stapsys,stapusr,stapdev",and added myself id in it . but when i run a simple test, the result is:

stap -v -e 'probe vfs.read {printf("read performed\n"); exit()}'

Pass 1: parsed user script and 95 library script(s) using 61820virt/22768res/2164shr/21336data kb, in 90usr/10sys/101real ms.
Pass 2: analyzed script: 1 probe(s), 1 function(s), 3 embed(s), 0 global(s) using 376660virt/164540res/8204shr/154120data kb, in 1380usr/150sys/1530real ms.
Pass 3: using cached /home/gabriel/.systemtap/cache/9b/stap_9be8ad6f6153f60f65fa3ddee5ad707d_1499.c
Pass 4: using cached /home/gabriel/.systemtap/cache/9b/stap_9be8ad6f6153f60f65fa3ddee5ad707d_1499.ko
Pass 5: starting run.
WARNING: /usr/local/systemtap/bin/staprun is not executable (Permission denied)
WARNING: /usr/local/systemtap/bin/staprun exited with status: 127
Pass 5: run completed in 0usr/0sys/0real ms.
Pass 5: run failed.  [man error::pass5]

Comment: What are the full permission bits on `/usr/local/systemtap/bin/staprun`, and what does `id` say about you?

Comment: I change the permission bits as "755", and then i execute the command, then it told me : ERROR: The effective user ID of staprun must be set to the root user.
  Check permissions on staprun and ensure it is a setuid root program.

Comment: To use the normal systemtap permission model, set permissions to back to the default setuid-root (`---s--x---. 1 root stapusr`), add yourself to stapdev, and log back in.